# How to add multiple images to div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add multiple image files for an element that was created in javascript. As you can see in the screenshot of the page, I am trying to add a different image for each div. The problem is I don't know how to do that for each div as it doesn't exist in my index.html.

I tried using a for loop and iterating each image src string onto the div but I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')"

This is what the DOM looks like with just one singular image for all of the cards. I want to make it so that each image is different. I have all the image files in my local directory.
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaGDi.png)

You can ignore the CSS portion.

```js
function getGame(){
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/?limit=40')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
   .then(function(data){
   data.results.forEach(function(version){
     fetchPokemonData(version); 
   })
  })
}
getGame();
function fetchPokemonData(version){
var url = version.url
  fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(pokeData){
    console.log(pokeData);
    renderPokemon(pokeData)
  })

}
function renderPokemon(pokeData){
  var allPokemonContainer = document.getElementById('poke-container');
  var pokeContainer = document.createElement("div")
  pokeContainer.classList.add('game', 'card',)


function getGame(){
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/?limit=40')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
   .then(function(data){
   data.results.forEach(function(version){
     fetchPokemonData(version); 
   })
  })
}
getGame();
function fetchPokemonData(version){
var url = version.url
  fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(pokeData){
    console.log(pokeData);
    renderPokemon(pokeData)
  })

}
function renderPokemon(pokeData){
  var allPokemonContainer = document.getElementById('poke-container');
  var pokeContainer = document.createElement("div")
  var gameLink = document.createElement('a')
  gameLink.classList.add('gameLink')
  pokeContainer.classList.add('game', 'card',)

  gamesImage(pokeContainer);

  var pokeName = document.createElement('h4')
  pokeDataName = pokeData.name
  pokeName.innerText = pokeDataName

  const hyphenRemove = pokeDataName.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  pokeName.innerText = hyphenRemove

  pokeName.classList.add('gameTitle')
 
  pokeContainer.append(pokeName);
  allPokemonContainer.append(pokeContainer)   
  
}
  var pokeName = document.createElement('h4')
  pokeDataName = pokeData.name
  pokeName.innerText = pokeDataName

  const hyphenRemove = pokeDataName.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  pokeName.innerText = hyphenRemove

  pokeName.classList.add('gameTitle')
 
  pokeContainer.append(pokeName);
  allPokemonContainer.append(pokeContainer)    
}
function gamesImage(containerDiv) {
  const images = [{
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'
      }, {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'
      },{
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale'
      }]
      // There will be more src imgs here. I haven't added them yet.
  var pokeImgContainer = document.createElement('div')
  pokeImgContainer.classList.add('image')

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
      var createImgTag = document.createElement('img');
      createImgTag = images[i].src;
      pokeImgContainer[i].appendChild(createImgTag);
  }
  containerDiv.append(pokeImgContainer);
}

//This is another approach I tried that didn't work:
//  function gamesImage(containerDiv) {
//   const imageFolder = [{
//            src: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'
//          }, {
//            src: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'
//          },{
//            src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale'
//          }]
//   var pokeImgContainer = document.createElement('div')
//   pokeImgContainer.classList.add('image')
  
//   document.querySelectorAll('.image').forEach((el, index) => {
//     var images = document.createElement('img');
//     images.setAttribute('src', imageFolder[index].src);
//     el.appendChild(images);
//     pokeImgContainer.appendChild.el;
//   })

  
//   containerDiv.appendChild(pokeImgContainer);
// }
```

```css
#poke-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
.gameTitle {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 7px;
 }
 .game {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Pokemon Games</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="poke-container">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the browser console? For example wouldn't this be a syntax error? `pokeContainer.classList.add('game', 'card',)`. The last `,` needs to be removed.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I don't get an error for that.

Comment: Oh okay, good. Can you make your code a running snippet as well (the `<>` button)? Provide some HTML as well, at least so that it runs. You can get replacement pictures from [picsum.photos](https://picsum.photos/)

Comment: Just added the snippet

Comment: Cool thanks! This seems incorrect to me: `createImgTag = images[i].src;` you want to set the `src` attribute on `createImgTag` but you are currently replacing the whole tag which the src. Also the next line: `pokeImgContainer[i].appendChild` - there I believe the `[i]` is incorrect since the container is not an array.

Comment: I added an answer with those two fixes and images are showing now. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I fixed the assignment of the image:

`createImgTag = images[i].src` - this is incorrect - you want to set the `src` attribute of the tag, not replace the tag. So fixing with:

```js
createImgTag.setAttribute("src", images[i].src);
```

`pokeImgContainer[i].appendChild` is incorrect. `pokeImgContainer` is not an array. Simply drop the `[i]`:

```js
pokeImgContainer.appendChild(createImgTag);
```

The snippet is now showing images.

I changed the images to an object, keyed by the game ID. The call to display an image receives the game's ID now and checks if `images[gameId]` exists in the function:

```js
gamesImage(pokeContainer, pokeData.id);
```

```js
function getGame(){
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/?limit=40')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
   .then(function(data){
   data.results.forEach(function(version){
     fetchPokemonData(version); 
   })
  })
}
getGame();

function fetchPokemonData(version){
var url = version.url
  fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(pokeData){
    //console.log(pokeData);
    renderPokemon(pokeData)
  })

}
function renderPokemon(pokeData){
  var allPokemonContainer = document.getElementById('poke-container');
  var pokeContainer = document.createElement("div")
  var gameLink = document.createElement('a')
  gameLink.classList.add('gameLink')
  pokeContainer.classList.add('game', 'card',)

  gamesImage(pokeContainer, pokeData.id);

  var pokeName = document.createElement('h4')
  pokeDataName = pokeData.name
  pokeName.innerText = pokeDataName

  const hyphenRemove = pokeDataName.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  pokeName.innerText = hyphenRemove

  console.log('renderPokemon() - Title', hyphenRemove);

  pokeName.classList.add('gameTitle')
 
  pokeContainer.append(pokeName);
  allPokemonContainer.append(pokeContainer)   
  
}
function gamesImage(containerDiv, gameId) {
  const images = {
      14: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'
      },
      15: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300'
      },
      16: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale'
      }}
      // There will be more src imgs here. I haven't added them yet.
  var pokeImgContainer = document.createElement('div')
  pokeImgContainer.classList.add('image')

  if (images[gameId]) {
    var createImgTag = document.createElement('img');
    createImgTag.setAttribute("src", images[gameId].src);
    pokeImgContainer.appendChild(createImgTag);
    containerDiv.append(pokeImgContainer);
  }
}
```

```css
#poke-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}
.gameTitle {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 7px;
 }
 .game {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Pokemon Games</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="poke-container">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! So it definitely did add multiple images like I wanted. However I want each card to have just one image of its own, not all three images in all the cards. I think that is what I was trying to achieve with 
```createImgTag = images[i].src; pokeImgContainer[i].appendChild(createImgTag);```

Comment: Ok so I tried it with the second approach (the commented out portion of the code) and it worked, but it shows 36 images of the same image per card. I only want one image per card. How do I make this work?

Comment: Well instead of the for loop over all images only take the first one (so `images[0]` if `images.length > 0`).

Comment: I updated the answer - by the way in your original snippet you define and run `getGame()` and `fetchPokemonData()` multiple times. I removed the extra ones for my snippet here.

Comment: Well if i only take the first image it only shows the first image. I want to show all the images. So one different image in each card.

Comment: I think the forEach method works. It just needs some tweaking and I need help figuring that part out

Comment: Oh in that case you can provide the `i` index of the picture to use to `gamesImage()` or even supply the picture to it directly.

Comment: So what would I write in the code?

Comment: I posted an update in the answer. I would change the images to an object keyed by the game's ID and then supply that ID in the function call.